# Open a window from menu bar (SwiftUI, MacOS)

Tags: macos, swiftui, appdelegate

I started working on an app for MacOS and got stuck on several issues. One of them is the following.

I have a UIElement app.

It's initialized in the following way:

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate

    var body: some Scene {
        Settings {
            EmptyView()
        }
    }
}
```

In my AppDelegate.swift I have:

```
import SwiftUI

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate, NSWindowDelegate {
    static private(set) var instance: AppDelegate!
    var settingsWindow: NSWindow!
    lazy var statusBarItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength)
    let menu = AppMenu()
    
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
        statusBarItem.button?.image = NSImage(
            systemSymbolName: "circle",
            accessibilityDescription: "My App"
        )
        statusBarItem.menu = menu.createMenu()
    }

    @objc func openSettingsWindow() {
        if settingsWindow == nil {
            let settingsView = SettingsView()
            settingsWindow = NSWindow(
                contentRect: NSRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 480, height: 300),
                styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable, .fullSizeContentView],
                backing: .buffered,
                defer: false
            )
            settingsWindow.center()
            settingsWindow.title = "Settings"
            settingsWindow.isReleasedWhenClosed = false
            settingsWindow.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: settingsView)
        }
        settingsWindow.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
    }
}
```

And the last, the menu is built like this:

```
import SwiftUI

class AppMenu: NSObject {
    let menu = NSMenu()

    func createMenu() -> NSMenu {
        // ...
        let settingsMenuItem = NSMenuItem(title: "Settings", action: #selector(settings), keyEquivalent: ",")
        settingsMenuItem.target = self
        menu.addItem(settingsMenuItem)
        // ...
        return menu
    }

    @objc func settings(sender: NSMenuItem) {
        NSApp.sendAction(#selector(AppDelegate.openSettingsWindow), to: nil, from: nil)
    }
}
```

But when I open the app in the menu bar and hit Settings the window with `SettingsView` is displayed randomly (I'm not sure what is exactly the reason for it being opened and not).

In the log section of Xcode I see warnings:

```
2023-05-29 21:39:57.172266+0200 My App[2211:1474025] [Window] Warning: Window NSMenuWindowManagerWindow 0x7fb8d4e21640 ordered front from a non-active application and may order beneath the active application's windows.
2023-05-29 21:40:02.197549+0200 My App[2211:1474025] [Window] Warning: Window NSWindow 0x7fb8d3717790 ordered front from a non-active application and may order beneath the active application's windows.
```

The first warning is fired when I hit the app icon in the menu bar (every time) and the second – when Settings is clicked.

My goal is to have an app without a window in docker but with an opportunity to open different windows via its menu bar items.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your settings window is opening each time, but calling from your status bar menu does not activate your app. Thus, it's hidden under other windows.

**Option 1:** Activate your app

```
settingsWindow.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)

NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true) // add this
```

**Option 2:** Raise window level

```
settingsWindow.level = NSWindow.Level.init(rawValue: 1)  // add this

settingsWindow.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
```

---

If you want an app without Dock icon, add this in your Info.plist:

```
LSUIElement = TRUE
```