# macOS: Opening statusbar menu and tapping menu item generate warnings

Tags: swift, macos, appkit, xcode-storyboard

This is the same issue as
[Open a window from menu bar (SwiftUI, MacOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76359975/open-a-window-from-menu-bar-swiftui-macos), except the solution doesn't work (anymore?).

First, when I press the icon:

> Warning: Window NSMenuWindowManagerWindow 0x7fa7fa823570 ordered front from a non-active application and may order beneath the active application's windows. // This one is gone now

When I tap the menu item, I receive the following warnings:

> CGSWindowShmemCreateWithPort failed on port 0
>
> CGSWindowShmemCreateWithPort failed on port 0
>
> CGSWindowShmemCreateWithPort failed on port 0
>
> CGSWindowShmemCreateWithPort failed on port 0
>
> CGSWindowShmemCreateWithPort failed on port 0 // This one is gone now
>
> Warning: Window NSWindow
> 0x7fa7fa829d20 ordered front from a non-active application and may
> order beneath the active application's windows.

After running the Window logic on `main`, `async` after activating the app, the Window warning went away:

```
@main
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    //...
    @IBAction
    func showPreferences(_ sender: Any) {
        guard let windowController = storyboard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "DataWindowController") as? NSWindowController else {
            return
        }

        guard let window = windowController.window else {
            return
        }

        if #available(macOS 14.0, *) {
            NSApp.activate()
        } else {
            NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            windowController.showWindow(self)
            window.orderFrontRegardless()
        }
    }
}
```

So apparently you cannot `activate` the app in the same runloop "tick" as you show the window but it's OK to do it right after.

But how do I get rid of the `NSMenuWindowManagerWindow` warning? This is all handled by the app itself through the `Main.storyboard`.

---

I managed to get rid of one `CGSWindowShmemCreateWithPort failed on port 0` by changing the following line:

```
-        window!.addTabbedWindow(newWindow, ordered: .above) // old way of adding a tab
+        window!.tabGroup?.addWindow(newWindow) // new way
```

That was found through using `` b libsystem_trace.dylib`_os_log_error_impl `` in the debug console

I was getting `error: Driver threw unknown argument: '-Wdeprecated-declarations' without emitting errors.` when I added that flag so I didn't find anything new after that.

Comment: The question you are referring to is a SwiftUI lifecycle app (without Storyboard). Please add a code example that displays the issue you are talking about.

Comment: @soundflix OK updated the example

Answer (score 1):

[`activate(ignoringOtherApps:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplication/1428468-activate) is deprecated starting macOS 14. If are targeting macOS 14, try to use the newer [`activate()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplication/4168336-activate).

[This thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/727803) on Apple developer gives some clues how to get rid of similar warnings or decide ignore with a warning, i.e. considering it "log noise".

Comment: I'm trying to suggestions one by one. Found out that I should use `tabGroup.addWindow` to make one of the port 0 errors to go away. Now experimenting with `-Wdeprecated-declarations`